# Computing significance of a hypothesis test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study

I am constructing a hypothesis test on a distribution $Bin(10,p)$, $H_0:p=0.5$ vs $H_1:p=0.55$.  I used R programming and I found the significance level when critical value is 8 to be 0.0546875. Why can't I get exactly 0.05?

Comment: Can you provide your R code?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "can't get"? After all, for the outcome $8$ the significance will be what it's going to be: it's completely determined by the problem. The same goes for all ten other outcomes, which means there are only eleven possible significance levels. Are you asking how to design a hypothesis test that will achieve *exactly* a $0.05$ level?

Comment: Hypothesis tests are not constructed "on a distribution". So it is quite hard to help. The answer will (with 94.5% certainty) be "because the binomial distribution function is discrete, i.e. a step function".

Comment: @whuber This is an exercise. This exercise asks me to find the critical value for which the significance level is about 0.05. I found it to be 8. The next question is to say why the significance level is not equal to 0.05!!

Comment: Look at it this way: (1) What is the significance level for $9$? (2) Assuming the answer to (1) is smaller than $0.05$, evidently you will need to find an outcome between $8$ and $9$ where the significant level of $0.05$ is attained. What are those outcomes?

Comment: @whuber As I understand it's not necessary to attain the 0.05 significance level because it is stated "about 0.05" but then it asks why we cannot get exactly 0.05!

Comment: We understand the question you're trying to answer, so don't keep repeating it - we're not doing your homework for you. Instead you're being given *very* clear and direct guidance about what to consider in thinking about the question. Consider *very carefully* what whuber has asked you to think about. I'd suggest you *step away from your computer*, grab a piece of paper, and start pondering the question and drawing some pictures of binomial pmfs or cdfs. What would you need to be true to get *exactly* 0.05? Why isn't that possible in this case?